# C#. Как добавить сервису (службе) доступ к базе SQL Server

Tags: c#

Есть приложение на C#, котрое отлично  работает. Но если этот же код вставить в сервис - то серверная часть работает, а часть которая отвечает за доступ к базе данных - не работает. Думаю тут дело в доступе. В самом коде конечно логин и пароль доступа к БД прописаны, и работают, но только не из службы.  Как запустить созданную службу, чтоб она могла читать  данные из SQL Server?

Comment: Вы рассуждаете об абстрактных конях в вакууме. У вас какая то конкретная ошибка? Можно с текстом ошибки ознакомиться?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46968725/5045688 - не?

Comment: Спасибо Александр, самое то!